# Mobile does not load the script on ListView element in page init event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

the script load all once on the html file loading so when I use event on pageinit or pagecreate and write in the event listview element with text data get by json the application write the html code without any script or style of jquery mobile

```
<div data-role="page" id="hteacher" >  
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Welcome teacher 1</h1>
 <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>

<div data-role="page" id="hteacher" >  
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Welcome teacher 1</h1>
 <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#hteacher" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t_addclass" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">ADD Class</a></li>
    <li><a href="#msg_page" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog">MSG</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

 <div data-role="content">
 <p></p>
 <h2>list of classes </h2>
 <ul data-role="listview" id="classes_list" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true"        data-filter="true">
 <script>
$( document ).delegate("#hteacher", "pagecreate", function() {
   var  html =  ' <li><a href="#"><img src="student1.jpg">BESHOY</a></li>';
   html +=  ' <li><a href="#"><img src="student2.jpg">MARY</a></li>';
  $("#classes_list").append (html );
          });

   </script>
   </ul>
  </div>

   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
   <h1>Welcome To .....</h1>
  </div>

  </div>    `
```

Comment: $("#classes_list").append (html ).listview("refresh");

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

In your html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="indexpage">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

<h1>Welcome teacher 1</h1>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#hteacher" data-icon="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#t_addclass" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">ADD Class</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#msg_page" data-icon="star" data-rel="dialog">MSG</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p></p>
     <h2>list of classes </h2>

    <ul data-role="listview" id="classes_list" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"></ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     <h1>Welcome To .....</h1>

</div>
</div>`
```

and script is:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#indexpage", function () {
var  text =  '<li><a href="#">BESHOY</a></li>';
text +=  ' <li><a href="#">MARY</a></li>';
$("#classes_list").append (text );

});
```

refer this fiddle for output [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/889uC/1/)